# How can I sharpen an image in OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

How can I sharpen an image using [OpenCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)?

There are many ways of smoothing or blurring but none that I could see of sharpening.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

One general procedure is laid out in [the Wikipedia article on unsharp masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking#Digital_unsharp_masking):

You use a Gaussian smoothing filter and subtract the smoothed version from the original image (in a weighted way so the values of a constant area remain constant).

To get a sharpened version of `frame` into `image`: (both `cv::Mat`)

```
cv::GaussianBlur(frame, image, cv::Size(0, 0), 3);
cv::addWeighted(frame, 1.5, image, -0.5, 0, image);
```

The parameters there are something you need to adjust for yourself.

There's also Laplacian sharpening, you should find something on that when you google.

Comment: Is there a way to replicate Photoshop's result of Unsharp Mask?

Comment: @Drazick Are you asking because it cannot be replicated? link to the wikipedia has been given above. [digital_unsharp_masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking#Digital_unsharp_masking) to be specific

Comment: @tilaprimera, I'm asking because Photoshop's USM is different from the "Classic" USM.

Comment: make sure `frame` is float32, not int8. Otherwise it will output an image with messed up rounding, which won't be noticeable visually, but will be clear on per-channel histogram.

Answer (score 73):

You can try a simple **kernel** and the **[filter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d)** function, e.g. in Python:

```
kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
im = cv2.filter2D(im, -1, kernel)
```

Wikipedia has a good overview of kernels with some more examples here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)

> In image processing, a kernel, convolution matrix, or mask is a small matrix. It is used for blurring, sharpening, embossing, edge detection, and more. This is accomplished by doing a convolution between a kernel and an image.

Comment: This is basically "laplacian" filter (8 -neighnors). It enhances the edges, corners etc. high frequency regions. 4-neighbors laplacian filter: [[0,-1,0],[-1,5,-1],[0,-1,0]].

Comment: Incorrect kernal variables for sharpening. Use these vars: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63864292/1594557

Comment: They are correct for a neighborhood of 8 pixels. The ones @leenremm linked are correct for a neighborhood of 4 pixels.

Answer (score 34):

You can sharpen an image using an [unsharp mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking). You can find more information about unsharp masking [here](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/unsharp.htm). And here's a Python implementation using OpenCV:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def unsharp_mask(image, kernel_size=(5, 5), sigma=1.0, amount=1.0, threshold=0):
    """Return a sharpened version of the image, using an unsharp mask."""
    blurred = cv.GaussianBlur(image, kernel_size, sigma)
    sharpened = float(amount + 1) * image - float(amount) * blurred
    sharpened = np.maximum(sharpened, np.zeros(sharpened.shape))
    sharpened = np.minimum(sharpened, 255 * np.ones(sharpened.shape))
    sharpened = sharpened.round().astype(np.uint8)
    if threshold > 0:
        low_contrast_mask = np.absolute(image - blurred) < threshold
        np.copyto(sharpened, image, where=low_contrast_mask)
    return sharpened

def example():
    image = cv.imread('my-image.jpg')
    sharpened_image = unsharp_mask(image)
    cv.imwrite('my-sharpened-image.jpg', sharpened_image)
```

Comment: this seems to be a pretty handy version. could you please add a little bit more info about the parameters. kernel size and sigma can be looked up in opencv, but what about amount and threshold? Thanks!

Comment: @choise `amount` is simply the amount of sharpening. For example, an `amount` of 2.0 gives a sharper image compared to the default value of 1.0. `threshold` is the threshold for the low-contrast mask. In other words, the pixels for which the difference between the input and blurred images is less than `threshold` will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 18):

> Any Image is a collection of signals of various frequencies. The
> higher frequencies control the edges and the lower frequencies control
> the image content. Edges are formed when there is a sharp transition
> from one pixel value to the other pixel value like 0 and 255 in
> adjacent cell. Obviously there is a sharp change and hence the edge
> and high frequency. For sharpening an image these transitions can be
> enhanced further.

One way is to convolve a self made filter kernel with the image.

```py
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    image = cv2.imread('images/input.jpg')
    kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], 
                       [-1, 9,-1],
                       [-1,-1,-1]])
    sharpened = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel) # applying the sharpening kernel to the input image & displaying it.
    cv2.imshow('Image Sharpening', sharpened)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

There is another method of subtracting a blurred version of image from bright version of it. This helps sharpening the image. But should be done with caution as we are just increasing the pixel values. Imagine a grayscale pixel value 190, which if multiplied by a weight of 2 makes if 380, but is trimmed of at 255 due to the maximum allowable pixel range. This is information loss and leads to washed out image.

```py
    addWeighted(frame, 1.5, image, -0.5, 0, image);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but shouldn't the kernel have 8 in the center and not 9?

Comment: @FarhoodET no, it must sum to 1 to preserve brightness. think about if image is constant

Answer (score 17):

You can find a sample code about **sharpening image using "unsharp mask" algorithm** at [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#details).

Changing values of `sigma`,`threshold`,`amount` will give different results.

```cpp
// sharpen image using "unsharp mask" algorithm
Mat blurred; double sigma = 1, threshold = 5, amount = 1;
GaussianBlur(img, blurred, Size(), sigma, sigma);
Mat lowContrastMask = abs(img - blurred) < threshold;
Mat sharpened = img*(1+amount) + blurred*(-amount);
img.copyTo(sharpened, lowContrastMask);
```

Answer (score 11):

For clarity in this topic, a few points really should be made:

1. Sharpening images is an ill-posed problem. In other words, blurring is a lossy operation, and going back from it is in general not possible.
2. To sharpen single images, you need to somehow add constraints (assumptions) on what kind of image it is you want, and how it has become blurred. This is the area of natural image statistics. Approaches to do sharpening hold these statistics explicitly or implicitly in their algorithms (deep learning being the most implicitly coded ones). The common approach of up-weighting some of the levels of a [DOG or Laplacian pyramid decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)#Laplacian_pyramid), which is the generalization of Brian Burns answer, assumes that a Gaussian blurring corrupted the image, and how the weighting is done is connected to assumptions on what was in the image to begin with.
3. Other sources of information can render the problem sharpening well-posed. Common such sources of information is video of a moving object, or multi-view setting. Sharpening in that setting is usually called [super-resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-resolution_imaging) (which is a very bad name for it, but it has stuck in academic circles). There has been [super-resolution methods in OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/superres/doc/super_resolution.html) since a long time.... although they usually dont work that well for real problems last I checked them out. I expect deep learning has produced some wonderful results here as well. Maybe someone will post in remarks on whats worthwhile out there.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try this filter

```py
sharpen_filter = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 5, -1], [0, -1, 0]])
sharped_img = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, sharpen_filter)
```

Answer (score 3):

To sharpen an image we can use the filter (as in many previous answers)

```
kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],[-1, 8, -1],[-1, -1, 0]], np.float32) 

kernel /= denominator * kernel
```

It will be the most when the denominator is 1 and will decrease as increased (2.3..)

The most used one is when the denominator is 3.

Below is the implementation.

```
kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],[-1, 8, -1],[-1, -1, 0]], np.float32) 

kernel = 1/3 * kernel

dst = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel)
```

Comment: Something seems to be missing near *"It will the most"*.

Answer (score -7):

Try with this:

```
cv::bilateralFilter(img, 9, 75, 75);
```

You might find more information [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html).

Comment: The question is about image sharpening, not edge preserving smoothing.