# Sharpen Image Filter

Tags: c#, image-processing, opencv, emgucv

I have code that takes an image saved on my computer and processes into a grayscale, smoothed gray, and canny edge image. What I would like it to do is sharpen the image by adding some type of filter to the image and then convert to gray and canny edge frame. I believe I have the code correct but when I run the program it doesn't seem to do anything different. Is the sharpen image in the wrong place? Is it somehow getting overlooked? Any suggestions please let me know.

```
      private void ProcessFrame()
  {
      String fileName = @"C:\filename";

               **Sharpen Image Filter code**
  public static Bitmap sharp(Bitmap img)
  {
      Bitmap sharpenImage = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

      int filterWidth = 3;
      int filterHeight = 3;
      int w = img.Width;
      int h = img.Height;

      double[,] filter = new double[filterWidth, filterHeight];

      filter[0, 0] = filter[0, 1] = filter[0, 2] = filter[1, 0] = filter[1, 2] = 
     filter[2,0]   =  filter[2, 1] = filter[2, 2] = -1;
      filter[1, 1] = 9;

      double factor = 1.0;
      double bias = 0.0;

      Color[,] result = new Color[img.Width, img.Height];

      for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x)
      {
          for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y)
          {
              double red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0;


              for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterWidth; filterX++)
              {
                  for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterHeight; filterY++)
                  {
                      int imageX = (x - filterWidth / 2 + filterX + w) % w;
                      int imageY = (y - filterHeight / 2 + filterY + h) % h;

                      Color imageColor = img.GetPixel(imageX, imageY);
                      red += imageColor.R * filter[filterX, filterY];
                      green += imageColor.G * filter[filterX, filterY];
                      blue += imageColor.B * filter[filterX, filterY];
                  }
                  int r = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * red + bias), 0), 255);
                  int g = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * green + bias), 0), 255);
                  int b = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * blue + bias), 0), 255);

                  result[x, y] = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
              }
          }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j)
          {
              sharpenImage.SetPixel(i, j, result[i, j]);
          }
      }
      return sharpenImage;
  } 

**Sharpen Image Code Ends**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I could be missing it, but it doesn't look like you are ever invoking your sharpening code on an image. That would certainly explain why the result isn't changing!

Comment: In the sharpen image code I changed 'img' to 'frame' because that was how the original image was coming in. Is that not correct?

Comment: "Sharp" is a method that takes a Bitmap as a parameter and returns a Bitmap. For the code inside that method to run, it needs to be called. Much like you call the method "foo" from inside the method "processFrame", except I assume you will need to convert from the OpenCV Image<T,U> type to a Bitmap type, or rewrite Sharp to use CV's classes. I would expect OpenCV to have a built in function to use.

Comment: For example : see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993082/how-to-sharpen-an-image-in-opencv