# How to zoom an image and keep its clearance?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jtq0wlbujm3p05/122.png). I resized it i obtain [another](https://www.dropbox.com/s/emxx6ssnjkyf6yf/xx.png) with a size greater than the first .

```
    resize(roi,zoom,Size(2274,70),(0.0),(0.0),3);
```

i also test all the method of interpplation but it don't give a good result.

```
     CV_INTER_NN (default)
     CV_INTER_LINEAR
     CV_INTER_CUBIC
     CV_INTER_AREA
```

The image contain text when i zoomed it it becomes so fuzzy and i can not recognize the text.

I ask for an algorithm or method to make the image more clear

Thanks for the help

Comment: You could provide links to the original *and* the corresponding result images in order to make sure we understand your situation correctly.

Comment: If your original image is just slightly smaller than the result that you linked, this is an expected result and it's very hard to write an algorithm that would work well in such a situation. Essentially, you should not scale an image but rather render a new one with a larger font and so on.

Comment: I cannot recognize the text in the original image either, at least not any better than in the zoomed version. I don't think any zooming algorithm can find detail that does not exist in the original image. I am afraid that you need to carefully re-think what it is that you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Pukku do you know what super resolution do in opencv ?

Comment: No, not really. But given e.g. this paper [http://www3.nd.edu/~jsimpkin/Citations/simpkinsSRCh2012.pdf], I believe you are supposed to have *a set* of input images.

Comment: Also if you have a suitable prior for a specific purpose, you may be able to do magic. But in general from a single image you can't recover information that simply is not there.

Comment: like pukku said, you can't recover data that was never there. maybe you could try to sharpen the image? try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993082/how-to-sharpen-an-image-in-opencv