# Workaround for opencv inpaint(with gradients) required

Tags: c++, opencv

How do you avoid gradients when use opencv inpaint?

Does anybody know implementations like patch tool or healing bursh?

Wolfram inpaint TextureSynthesis?

[image]

Comment: Could you give more details ? Ok for opencv inpainting, but what are `path tool` and `healing bursh`?

Comment: It's examples of photoshop tools provided by designer. Just to compare with opencv inpaint

Comment: ok. It's hard to answer your question as you are comparing results from an opensource tool to proprietary software. But AFAIK, the opencv inpainting function provides some parameters that you can play with. Have you tried these ? If yes, I am afraid you won't get further without additional processing. Maybe sharpen the considered area using a mask. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4993082/193789).