# Matlab image segmentation for liver

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am struggling in segmentation of images in matlab. My goal is to extract liver from ct scan images. [image: This is sample image].

I extracted liver for this sample image and the output is like this [image: Output image for sample image].
My implementation code is

```
function [] = Code4( image_file )
image = imread(image_file);       
[height, width, planes] = size(image);
rgb = reshape(image, height, width * planes);
r = image(:, :, 1);             
g = image(:, :, 2);             
b = image(:, :, 3);             

% since r,g & b are of equeal values, we will be considering only r.

mask=r>120 & r<140 ;  % range of color component for liver
labels = bwlabel(mask);
id = labels(111, 200);

% get the mask containing only the desired object
liver = (labels == id);
imagesc(liver);
colorbar;

end
```

My problem is when I change image , rgb value of liver section may be different.
Here is other sample image

[image: Sample image 2].

For this image rgb value vary from 160 to 190 for each color component (r, g & b). Please help me to solve the problem.

Here is other sample image with rgb range varying from 110 to 180 
[image: sample image 3].

Please help.

Comment: You can not segment a CT image by value. It has noise and CT values will change. You need to use some better semgentation techniques, such as level sets

Comment: @AnderBiguri Can you please provide details about it?

Comment: I would try to find contours in 1st derivate of image, then enlarge it by morphology operations to ennsure no gaps and then fill it with flood fill

Comment: Also take a look at [Fracture detection in hand using image proccessing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36881389/2521214)

Comment: @swapnilgandhi No, its too complicated for Stackoverflow. You'd need to read some papers/books

Comment: Do you find matlab code that works for any kind images?

Comment: @Sridharan my code runs on specific set of images. If you want i can comment the link of code and images

Comment: Please comment the link!!

Comment: my mail id jjsridharan@gmail.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using fixed thresholds, you can try to cluster the image by gray levels. As a preprocessing step, I would suggest using morphological opening to make the difference of gray levels of the neighboring pixels small, so you have less noise in the clustered image.

Below I apply two successive morphological openings to the image using a `3x3` circular kernel, and then apply k-means clustering to the gray levels. From your sample images and some I found on the internet, I decided to set `k = 4`. If you are using high-resolution images, first downsample them to dimensions ~400-600. Otherwise the morphological operation may not have a significant effect, and the k-means will be slow.

Below are some of the opened and segmented images. Of course there's more to be done in terms of

- separating out the liver region
- generalizing this to a large dataset

but hope this is at least a starting point.

I don't have `matlab`, so the code is in `c++` and `opencv`, but the conversion should be simple as it involves only morphological and clustering operations, it should be somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27328192/2571705).

**Update**
You might be able to narrow down the region or interest by filtering out the darkest and the lightest regions from the segmented image. For this, use the k-means cluster centers, check for the extreme values (max and min) and remove the corresponding k values from the labeled image. Then you can look for large structures to the left of the result image. Worst case, you might get a hole on the left side when the extreme region filtering goes wrong. I've updated the code and results.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]
[image: 8]
[image: 9]
[image: 10]
[image: 11]
[image: 12]
[image: 13]
[image: 14]
[image: 15]

opencv c++ code

```
// load image as gray scale
Mat im = imread("5.jpg", 0);
// morphological opening
Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
Mat morph;
morphologyEx(im, morph, CV_MOP_OPEN, kernel, Point(-1, -1), 2);
// clustering
int k = 4;
Mat segment, lbl;
vector<float> centers;
morph.convertTo(segment, CV_32F);
int imsize[] = {segment.rows, segment.cols};
Mat color = segment.reshape(1, segment.rows*segment.cols);
kmeans(color, k, lbl, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0), k, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
lbl = lbl.reshape(1, 2, imsize);

// find argmin and argmax to find extreme gray level regions
int minidx = min_element(centers.begin(), centers.end()) - centers.begin();
int maxidx = max_element(centers.begin(), centers.end()) - centers.begin();
// prepare a mask to filter extreme gray level regions
Mat mask = (lbl != minidx) ^ (lbl == maxidx);

// only for display purposes
Mat lbldisp;
lbl.convertTo(lbldisp, CV_8U, 255.0/(k-1));
Mat lblColor;
applyColorMap(lbldisp, lblColor, COLORMAP_JET);
// region of interest
Mat roiColor = Mat::zeros(lblColor.size(), CV_8UC3);
lblColor.copyTo(roiColor, mask);

imshow("opened", morph);
imshow("segmented", lblColor);
imshow("roi", roiColor);
waitKey();
```

Comment: I would very much like to know the reasons for any downvotes, so I can improve my answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote and find your answer actually quite interesting, but the question is completely off-topic for Stack Overflow. This is not a programming question but an image processing research project. Your answer definitely points in the right direction, but answers to off-topic questions are generally poorly received.

Comment: @dasdingonesin Thanks. I just found the question interesting and thought of sharing what I tried. :)