# How do I refine the outline of an image from a mask?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, vision

I have an image, and I can obtain a mask of the image as so

[image: Original Image]

[image: Mask of the image]

Now the mask is nearly perfect, but it is still clearly rough around the edges. For example, if I apply a blur effect to the background, there are portions around the ROI that are from the background, and look quite bad (Notice the area around the arms and right hip)

[image: Blurred image]

Could someone tell me how to refine the mask further to encompass only the ROI and not any part of the background? I'm using OpenCV and Tensorflow currently. The Grabcut algorithm of OpenCV wasn't too much help.

Comment: Try applying erosion on the image. It should help regarding the areas near the hair and heap. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html

Comment: Maybe you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993082/how-to-sharpen-an-image-in-opencv

Comment: @Tahlil I tried this, in fact I had tried erosion and dilation previously too, I had forgotten to mention it. The end result is not much of an improvement.

Comment: @NilsSchlüter I tried the method described, not much help in this case