# How can we read a blurred image using pytesseract?

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am using pytesseract ocr to read the text of the image, but i am getting a false output for blurry images shown below.

[image]

How can I make the above image or such images ocr ready.

Comment: I'd recommend retaking the photographs if possible, but I doubt that's possible if you're asking this... lol

Comment: Haha what I mean is how can I sharpen a blur image like above(Changed the image) readable for pytesseract.

Comment: I think this helps. Explained very clearly.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54465855/11049657