# How do I remove extra luminescence in a image which cause feature lost in a image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am having a person's face image which has extra luminescence while capturing the photo. I want reduce or remove the luminescence of the image so that face is clearly visible.

Example of the Image is :

[image]

[image]

I am using python and OpenCV to do it.I have converted it to gray scale and perform histogram equalization but it didn't give desired output.

Comment: Try sharpening: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993082/how-can-i-sharpen-an-image-in-opencv

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.But it does not work on given examples as light effect is not changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images you want to correct are lost color information, overexposed regions become white. And you cant restore their color with traditional cv methods. The only way I see is to train GAN network for this task. But no guaranty that result will be perfect.